# Tabs - Highlight Active Tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 tabs, be default the first tab is highlight.  I write some JQuery to highlight a selected tab, or active tab, but somehow it doesn't work.

Please give a hand.

Thanks

```
<div class="tabs tab-active" id="tab-part1">Etiam</div>
<div class="tabs" id="tab-part2">CatM1(LTE)</div>
<div class="tabs" id="tab-part3">LTE</div>
<div class="tab-parts">
<div id="part1">
This is part1
</div>
<div id="part2">
This is part2
</div>
<div id="part3">
This is part3
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(function () {
     $('#tab-part1').click((event) => {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('tab-active');
        $(this).addClass('tab-active');
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part2, .tab-parts #part3').hide();
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part1').show();
     });
     $('#tab-part2').click((event) => {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('tab-active');
        $(this).addClass('tab-active');
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part1, .tab-parts #part3').hide();
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part2').show();

     });
     $('#tab-part3').click((event) => {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('tab-active');
        $(this).addClass('tab-active');
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part1, .tab-parts #part2').hide();
        $(this).find('.tab-parts #part3').show();
     });
 });
```

[This is its jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0vL9yuk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have different click handlers for each of the different tabs. Instead handle it in one event handler only like this:

```
$(function () {
     $('.tabs').click((event) => {
        const tab = $(event.target);
        const activeTab = $('.tab-active');
        activeTab.removeClass('tab-active')
        tab.addClass('tab-active');
     });
 });
```

EDIT: Additional logic will be needed to show hide the text below, but that should be simple enough. I have focussed on solving your problem statement of handling active tabs.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/so17whdc/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Gurtej Singh and Mauricio Contreras!  It is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace your (event) with function, because when you do this `(event) => $(this)` 'this' references to event, thats the click event not the element

```
          $(function () {
     $('#tab-part1').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('tab-active');
        $(document).find('.tab-parts #part2, .tab-parts #part3').hide();
        $(this).addClass('tab-active');
        $(document).find('.tab-parts #part1').show();
     });
     $('#tab-part2').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('tab-active');
        $(this).addClass('tab-active');
        $(document).find('.tab-parts #part1, .tab-parts #part3').hide();
        $(document).find('.tab-parts #part2').show();

     });
     $('#tab-part3').click(function(){
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('tab-active');
            $(this).addClass('tab-active');
        $(document).find('.tab-parts #part1, .tab-parts #part2').hide();
        $(document).find('.tab-parts #part3').show();
     });
 });
```